# Defaultdict not returning default values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d1 = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict (lambda : 0)))
d1['first']['second'] = 2 #Assigning some value
d1['first']['third']   #Expecting to return the default value, which is 0, but ...
defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7ff5765421e0>, {})
```

Why is this not returning 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are three levels of `defaultdict`s until you reach the value `0`, so you need to do:

```
>>> d1['first']['second']['third']
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 levels of `defaultdict`. So to get the default value you need 3 indexes.

```
print(d1[1][2][3])
```